# WPF application layout differences between debug and release build

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, frontend

We have a quite simple app made in WPF in visual studio for adding data to the DB. It has validation on the data and if the validation fails red error messages appear indicating what is wrong and the textboxes with the invalid data are surrounded with a red border. 
This works all fine in debug mode. When we make a release build or when we run the app in release mode in VS, the red borders are not there, but the red error messages do still appear, indicating the validation is still successful.

Why would a red border be shown in debug but not in release? Has anyone had a similar issue? Can someone maybe pinpoint me in the direction I should look?

Also if I put breakpoints in my code, they are not hit when in release mode, even though advanced build settings > debugging information is on full and in the debugging properties the just-my-code is disabled.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edited:**

XAML code

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding CredentialLogin, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="4">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoginValid}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

C# code

```
    var result = _validator.Validate(validationModel);
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {

                if (result.Errors.Any(e => e.PropertyName.Equals($"Entity.{nameof(SystemCredential.Username)}",
                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                    IsLoginValid = false;


                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ValidationMessages.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                }

                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(ValidationMessages))
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(IsLoginValid));

                return false; 
    }
```

This is a slightly shortened version of the code, there are more validations but I only show the username one, the rest is practically the same, just other properties

Comment: Could you share some of your code? A breakpoint not hitting in the Release config does not necessarily mean that your code isn't run, just that the code in your file and the executed IL instructions don't match.

Comment: which part would you like to see, because I didn't really know what code would be interesting to share...

Comment: The XAML code where the error message should appear and the C# code which sets the code (and is not hit).

Comment: i hope this part of the code can help...

Comment: What is the difference between the Debug and Release in the Build tab of your app Properties?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT no difference except for the option "define debug constant" being checked for the debug options and it being unchecked for the release options...

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the info you provided,could you show more? (Don't include any personal info)